# Retrieve EOS LINK tokens sent by mistake to Ledger Nano S

Tags: transactions

How to retrieve my LINK Tokens sent by mistake to my Ledger Nano S and transfer them to My Ether Wallet.
I cannot see them in my Ledger Live, but I found the transaction in my Etherscan.io

Thank you.

Comment: The coins do not appear in your wallet? Are you sure the addresses match? One small mistake can be an entirely different wallet.

Comment: What is the ticker (three-four letter code) for the token?

Comment: The address match totally.

Comment: the ticker is "LINK". the coin is CHAINLINK.

Comment: You said EOS, but when I check the Token it says it is an Ethereum token. Could it have been sent to the wrong coin's address?

Comment: MyEtherWallet has support for accessing your hardware wallet. You can use it to move the tokens to somewhere else.

Comment: I can access my hardware wallet through MyEtherWallet. But I cannot see the Token because as I said it is not supported by Ledger. I only see the transaction in my Etherscan.io and that is why I think the only way to retreive the Tokens is if there is a way to transfer them through Etherscan.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There guide to accessing your ERC20 Token via Ledger Live. If you still have access to your coins and sent them properly, then [this](https://support.ledger.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005197845-Manage-ERC20-tokens) is how you would access them.

Comment: You are right. It is an ERC20 Token, but not supported by Ledger. That is why I cannot see it in my Ledger. I am looking for a way, if possible, to forward it to my Ethereum Wallet from my Etherscan.io where I can see the transaction.